# Flask: Turn on DEBUG only for web views blueprint

Tags: python, flask

In a flask app I'm developing, I have some web views, which return a normal web page content and an API blueprint. For development configuration, I turn on debug, which is handy to see the backtrace in a browser:

```
DEBUG = True
```

However, this also applies to the API blueprint. Dumping HTML content into the console when doing a request through `httpie` is not very nice. Is there a way to have debug only for the web views and not for the APIs?